# Python: ValueError: time data '2021:6:22' does not match format '%Y:-%m:-%d'

Tags: python-3.x

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему вываливается такая ошибка при попытке перевести string в datetime?

```
ValueError: time data '2021:6:22' does not match format '%Y:-%m:-%d'
```

Сам перевод организовываю так:

```
count_data_for_interval_clicks_dict = [{'count': int(row[0]), 'date': datetime.strptime(str(int(row[1]))+':'+str(int(row[2]))+':'+str(int(row[3])), '%Y:-%m:-%d')} for row in count_data_for_interval_clicks.all()][:10]
```

Когда использую такое: '%Y:%-m:%-d', то он пишет, что '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y:%-m:%-d'.

Но вроде как в документации указано, что я могу использовать %-m, %-d, если Month as a decimal number и Day of the month as a decimal number соответственно, как в моем случае.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes покажите где там в таблице есть хоть упоминание `%-m`

Comment: @ArchDemon во всяких мануалах встречается. Откуда взято - непонятно. Вот например https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы неправильно преобразовываете строку в datetime-формат. Вы пишите: `'%Y:%-m:%-d'`, а должно быть: `'%Y:%m:%d'`.

Пример:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = '2018:6:29 08:15:27.243860'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(date_time_obj)
```

Comment: Не должно быть. В дате в вопросе элементы разделены именно двоеточиями.

Comment: @Эникейщик тогда же будет возникать ошибка. Если рассматривать пример автора вопроса, то ему, исходя из моего ответа, просто нужно убрать `:`

Comment: о том и вопрос - какой формат сделать, чтобы не было ошибки

Comment: @Эникейщик понял, не заметил

Comment: @Эникейщик исправлено, работает с примером автора.

Comment: Странно, но почему-то Ваш совет сработал. Я вроде несколько раз тоже так пробовал. Может что не доглядел. Спасибо!